# Dockerfile: what to copy for multistage build for packaging python and app together

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

So, I have a python application as below

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN (pip install  /app/requirements.txt)

CMD ["/app/run_my_app.py"]
```

then, i would build it as myapp

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

and it runs fine with

```
docker run myapp
```

Now I want to create subsequent images which runs the above python app container in different OS. For example, it could be a centos, ubuntu, etc.

Dockerfile

```
FROM myapp as myapp
CMD ["bash"]

FROM ubuntu # this could be centos, etc
COPY --from=myapp /app /app
CMD [/app/run_my_app.py]
```

i built it with

```
docker build -t ubuntuapp .
```

when i do

```
docker run ubuntuapp
```

it fails because there is no python installation under ubuntu. how do i package both python and my python app so that when it copies /app it can just run it?

one way may be installing python into a custom dir i.e. /app/python  and have /app/run_my_app.py shebang with /app/python/bin/python

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of installing python yourself, the container-set-of-mind approach would be to find an image which comes with the environment you need: [centos](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-27-centos7/), [ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/r/pramttl/ubuntu-python/) ..

Comment: @Arne this is a very simple example. i need to do a whole lot more under centos/ubunt like setting up autmounts, ldap, etc. I just want a container image which packaged everything it needs to run and be able to inherit in another container image